# Update Firefox in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, software-installation, firefox

first of all I am Karthik and I am new to Linux. I heared about Ubuntu and I switched to it from Windows 10. I liked the style and efficiency of Ubuntu. I am using Ubuntu 12.10.... I need to know more about Ubuntu. First of all my firefox web browser is outdated. How can I update it? and how can i install any other softwares? Any help will be thankful.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 reached end of life in 2014-04-30 and doesn't get updates any more.  Please use a more recent version of Ubuntu, like Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.10 is an old, non-LTS version, and is not supported nowadays. The currently supported versions are 12.04, 14.04, 15.04 and 15.10. You won't be able to make security updates and find newer package versions in such an old Ubuntu version. Please consider upgrading.